# Implicit function theorem and path-connected components

Tags: general-topology, continuity, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function-theorem, path-connected

Suppose I have two $C^1$ functions $F$ and $G$  which go from $\mathbb{R}^N$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Suppose at a point $x_0\in\mathbb{R}^N$, I know that $F(x_0)=0$ and $G(x_0)=0$.

Suppose further that I know the gradients of $F$ and $G$ at $x_0$ are non-zero, i.e; $\nabla F(x_0)\neq 0$ and  $\nabla G(x_0)\neq 0$.

Consider the zero sets of $F$ and $G$ locally around $x_0$, $Z_F =\{x|F(x)=0\}$ and $Z_G =\{x|G(x)=0\}$. By Implicit Function Theorem, we know that $Z_F$ and $Z_G$ are continuous smooth $N-1$ dimensional graphs of functions. Further, $Z_F$ and $Z_G$ each partition the space around $x_0$ locally into 2 path-connected components (the regions above and below each graph).

My question is this: Is it true that in general $Z_F$ and $Z_G$ together partition a neighbourhood of $x_0$ into at most $4$ path-connected components? If so how do I show it and if not what is a counterexample?

Comment: I haven't thought this through, but my guess is that this is not true. I would begin by checking out $F(x,y,z)=z$ and $G(x,y,z)=z-xy$ around $x_0=(0,0,0)$. Possibly also $G(x,y,z)=x-xy(x+y)(x-y)$. Something exceptionally often happens when $\nabla F(x_0)$ and $\nabla G(x_0)$ are parallel (linearly dependent).

Comment: Hmm that is a good point... thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: graph]

Your graphs may pretty well end up like this and still be $C^1$.

Comment: But does the Implicit function theorem say that the implicit function would also be continuously differentiable? Is this function differentiable at the centre point?

Comment: *continuously differentiable

Comment: Why, of course it is.

Comment: The derivative isn't continuous at the centre point I thought?

Comment: Is it a general result or do you have in mind some specific function which resembles my graph?

Comment: Well it looks to me that you have the sine wave oscillating more and more as you get closer to the axis (something like y=x sin(pi/x)), in which case you can choose a sequence of points (wherever the sine wave touches the axis) where the derivative is 1 which tend to the center point and a sequence of points (wherever the sine wave touches the curve) where the derivative is 0. The limit of the first sequence is 1 the second is zero. Therefore the derivative can't be continuous at the center point surely?

Comment: What if you try $x^3\sin{1\over x}$?

Comment: Doesn't the derivative of $x^3\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ have a discontinuity at $0$?

Comment: Can't you take the derivative and see that for yourself?

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(x^3\sin(\frac{1}{x}))=x (-\cos(\frac{1}{x}) + 3 x \sin(\frac{1}{x}))$ which has a discontinuity at $x=0$.

Comment: $\cos{1\over x}$ does have a discontinuity at zero, but $x\cdot\cos{1\over x}$ doesn't.

Comment: $x\cos(\frac{1}{x})$ is only well defined on $\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: Then  take a derivative at 0 using the definition. (Shall I remind that the function itself at 0 is defined as 0?)

Comment: hmm okay I see... thank you